# ISO8601 format support in python datetime module

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601

I have read so many questions on parsing ISO8601 in python but most of them use external dependencies.
Then i bumped in to this question,

[How to parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date/15228038)

It explains that python doesn't support iso8601 formatting, but the answer is 3 years old.

I need to parse this date without using any external dependencies,

```
from datetime import datetime
app_login = "1996-12-19T16:39:57+08:00"
parse_app_login = datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
print(parse_app_login)
```

I get error:

```
ValueError: time data '1996-12-19T16:39:57+08:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
```

i want to know why python does not support iso8601 format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that `Python 3.7` support `ISO8601` UTC offsets format,

[From Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior),

> **Changed in version 3.7:** When the %z directive is provided to the
>   strptime() method, the UTC offsets can have a colon as a separator
>   between hours, minutes and seconds. For example, '+01:00:00' will be
>   parsed as an offset of one hour. In addition, providing 'Z' is
>   identical to '+00:00'.

using Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47),

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> x = "2018-10-18T16:39:57+08:00"
>>> y = datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
>>> print(y)
```

**Output,**

```
2018-10-18 16:39:57+08:00
```